# Which algebraic real numbers are eigenvalues of a finite graph?

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, algebraic-numbers

Since the adjacency matrix of a finite graph has integer entries, its eigenvalues are algebraic. Since the adjacency matrix is also symmetric, the eigenvalues are all real. Can all algebraic real numbers be produced by this way? Or are there algebraic numbers which are not realized as any of the eigenvalues of the adjacency matrix of any finite graph?

Comment: No, a necessary condition is that the sums of the powers of the eigenvalues are nonnegative. There's a more complicated necessary condition that IIRC is sufficient for being the adjacency matrix of a directed multigraph but I won't be able to pull up the reference for a bit.

Comment: Thank you! I don't totally understand, which powers?

Comment: All the powers; the power sums correspond to counts of closed walks on the graph. Here's the related question I asked: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3939/when-is-a-monic-integer-polynomial-the-characteristic-polynomial-of-a-non-negati

Comment: Sorry, I'm being a bit careless. If you only want to characterize the single eigenvalues (rather than sets of eigenvalues) then the condition I gave doesn't obviously stop you. On the other hand a condition that does stop you is that all the conjugates must also be real, which isn't satisfied by e.g. $\sqrt[3]{2}$.

Comment: Haha I was just going to ask about that! This makes much more sense, thanks :) If you'd like to make that an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a real algebraic integer $\alpha$ is an eigenvalue of a symmetric adjacency matrix $A$, all its conjugates must also be eigenvalues of $A$, so a necessary condition is that all of the conjugates of $\alpha$ must be real. So, for example, $\alpha = \sqrt[3]{2}$, whose conjugates are $\sqrt[3]{2} \omega$ and $\sqrt[3]{2} \omega^2$, is not such an algebraic integer.

If we want to characterize which sets of eigenvalues $\alpha_1, \dots \alpha_k$ can occur (and not just which individual eigenvalues) then a stronger necessary condition is that

$$\text{tr}(A^n) = \sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i^n \ge 0$$

for all $n$; these traces count closed walks on the corresponding graph. Actually we must also have the more complicated condition

$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{d \mid n} \mu(d) \text{tr}(A^{n/d}) \ge 0$$

where these numbers count *aperiodic* closed walks. Some years ago I asked [on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3939/when-is-a-monic-integer-polynomial-the-characteristic-polynomial-of-a-non-negati) whether this necessary condition characterizes eigenvalues of the adjacency matrices of directed multigraphs (equialently, matrices with non-negative integer entries, not necessarily symmetric) and the answer turns out to be [yes](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.309.2880&rep=rep1&type=pdf). That paper references other papers addressing the question for non-negative symmetric matrices but seems to imply that the question is open in general.

Answer (score 5):

See Salez: https://arxiv.org/abs/1302.4423: an algebraic integer is an eigenvalue of a graph if and only if it, and all its conjugates, are real. (Equivalently all roots of its minimal polynomial are real.)

This was first proved by Estes (see the references in the cited paper). Salez actually proves that a totally real algebraic integer is an eigenvalue of a tree.

Comment: This is awesome, thank you!